# div contentEditable but Readonly

Tags: html, contenteditable, readonly

I have a div with some text and I want when the cursor is hover this div to select the text. If I let this div as it is, when trying to select all (CTRL+A) then I select all page content, meaning all body text.

To get rid of this, I need to use contenteditable attribute for this div.

But I don't want to let people to change the text / copy / cut and so on

I try to use readonly for this div, but doesn't working.

Any advice please ?

PS1: This div has also other tags inside (html content), but I don't think that this is a problem.

PS2: An example is here: jsfiddle.net/msakamoto_sf/wfae8hzv/ - but with a problem. You can cut the text :(

Comment: use `contenteditable="false"` will not allow to cut the text.

Comment: Yes, and not allowed to select the text from the div using CTRL + A. Please read my post.

Comment: Ohh ok it's issue in chrome. I am checking it in firefox. In firefox it's working.

Comment: I'm testing in firefox too ( Version 37 ). Here is a test for what are you saying: https://jsfiddle.net/wq9d66t1/. You can not select the text inside div using CTRL + A (only the text inside div)

Comment: I am using 37.0.2 and i can able to select here.http://jsfiddle.net/wfae8hzv/17/

Comment: Please understand the role of CTRL + A. Select here http://jsfiddle.net/wfae8hzv/18/ the text inside div using CTRL + A. You will also select the text " text outside div " witch is outside div. Just use CTRL + A short keys. This is actually my problem. I want to be able to select only the text inside div using CTRL + A

Comment: Ok so you need something like:  http://jsfiddle.net/wfae8hzv/20/ ?

Comment: Yes ketan. Seems like is working fine. Thank you very much.

Comment: For what it's worth, I just came across the "contentReadOnly" command on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Editable_content which seems to be exactly what OP was looking for. I haven't been able to get it working, though, so maybe I'm misinterpreting the docs…?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can prevent the user from cutting by handling the "cut" event and calling its `preventDefault()` method. This will prevent cut with any user input (including the browser's context menu or edit menu), not just via a particular key combination.

This example uses jQuery because your jsFiddle uses it:

```
$("#editablediv").on("cut", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: To further imitate a `textarea` with a `readonly` attribute, you would need to also `preventDefault()` on the `paste` and `keypress` events along with `cut`.

Answer (score 15):

Use `event.metaKey` in the `keydown` event to check if ctrl (or cmd on mac) keys are being pressed. You also have to disable the `cut` and `paste` events.

```
<div
  contenteditable="true"
  oncut="return false"
  onpaste="return false"
  onkeydown="if(event.metaKey) return true; return false;">
    content goes here
</div>
```

Comment: this is the correct solution since turning off content editable changes the appearance of the tag (ie placeholders)

Answer (score 5):

set contenteditable to false and it should work !! that simple.

use contenteditable attribute  for div to make it editable or not
and use readonly attr for form input elements.

```
<element contenteditable="true|false">

<input readonly="readonly" />
```

Answer (score 4):

add this attribute to div contenteditable:

```
onbeforeinput="return false"
```

Comment: This is the only one that is both simple and works reliably enough. Though in my case I used the javascript equivalent:
`field.addEventListener("beforeinput", (e)=>e.preventDefault());`

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example in React, but it would work with basic HTML and JavaScript as well because I'm just leveraging the default events.

```
// import CSS
import './DefaultSettings.css';

// import packages
import React, { Component } from 'react';

// import components

const noop = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  return false;
};

class DefaultSettings extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="DefaultSettings"
        contentEditable={true}
        onCut={noop}
        onCopy={noop}
        onPaste={noop}
        onKeyDown={noop}>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default DefaultSettings;
```

Answer (score 0):

To prevent ctrl + x (Cut) from div you need to use following JQuery :

```
if (event.ctrlKey && event.keyCode === 88) 
{
   return false;
}
```

It will prevent to cut text from div.

Check [Fiddle Here.](http://jsfiddle.net/wfae8hzv/20/)

Comment: That won't cover the case when the user use the "Cut" option from the browser's context menu or edit menu.

Answer (score -1):

on user id condition set contentEditable="false"

Answer (score -3):

for JavaScript,

**`document.getElementById(divid).contentEditable = "false";`**

this will work